# What is the syntax for referring to a combobox on a form in vba for access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Here is what I've tried. What is wrong with this syntax. When I run this code I get a parameter value error message after selecting a value in combo52.

```
Private Sub Combo52_AfterUpdate()

With Forms("UserForm").Combo56
    If IsNull(Forms("UserForm").Combo52) Then
        .RowSource = ""
    Else
        .RowSource = "SELECT [PayGroupCountryDesc] " & _
                     "FROM HRBI " & _
                     "WHERE [PayGroupRegionCode]=" & Forms("UserForm").Combo52
    End If
    Call .Requery
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried and the immediate window shows Null

Comment: When Combo52 is Null I'd like all values in [PayGroupCountryDesc]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the value of a form field in your query you should use the exclamation mark (!) as a separator instead of a dot (.) and you should put `[Forms]` before the name:

```
    .RowSource = "SELECT [PayGroupCountryDesc] " & _
                 "FROM HRBI " & _
                 "WHERE [PayGroupRegionCode]=[Forms]![UserForm]![Combo52];"
```

Comment: Should the (!) be used throughout or just in SQL code?

Comment: I tried it, but I am still getting an "Enter Parameter Value". For some reason my Combo56 is not recognizing the value I select in Combo52